# Generate named colors in tikz figure in structured way

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I auto generate a lot of tikz-pictures that I use in a latex document. Some elements have their own color, that depends on some numerical values, which I want to use in the text to better illustrate which element I am talking about. The problem now, considering there are lots of these pictures with their own colors, is how to declare them and how to reference them in order that I won't get confused. Is there any "namespace" concept in latex? Or any other way to create a "local" color that can then be globally addressed by, for example, the label of the figure?

for example, here is a simple figure that illustrates the problem:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikz}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{66,62,195}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\LARGE]
\draw [ color=mycolor] (20.75,10.5) rectangle (16,13.25);
\end{tikz}
}
\label{fig:my_label}
\caption{\textcolor{REFERENCE HERE}{COLORED TEXT}}
\end{figure}
```

I am not sure how to reference `mycolor` from the caption, or define the colors in a modular way, so that the names don't overlap for multiple generated tikz figures.

Comment: `\tikzstyle` is obsolete. You should avoid using `\resizebox` for elements which might contain text and the syntax `\begin{tikz} ... \end{tikz}` only works by accident. You probably want to use a `tikzpicture` instead

Comment: Why don't you just define the color in the document preamble? Then you can use in throughout the whole document (and also in Ti*k*Z drawings in this document). Or, if you want the color to be scoped in the `figure`, define it inside the `figure` environment, but outside the Ti*k*Z environment.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example as to what these elements are? I mean in your example you use same color for all nodes + caption, so is this what you call elements?

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need to generate names for colors in a very complicated manner for what you want to achieve. Rather, it is just a matter of scoping, that is of defining and redefining colors inside scopes.

If you want to use a color throughout the document, define it in the preamble. If you want to use it inside a certain scope, such as a `figure` environment, (re-)define it inside this environment. Once defined, the color is available inside the relevant scope. If you want to use the color in the caption as well (that is, outside the `tikzpicture`, but inside the `figure`), just define it at the relevant position.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% define color for whole document
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{255,0,0}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    % redefine color for this figure only
    \definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0,255,0}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\LARGE}]
        \draw[color=mycolor] (20.75,10.5) rectangle (16,13.25);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \label{fig:my_labelA}
    \caption{\textcolor{mycolor}{COLORED TEXT}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    % redefine color for this figure only
    \definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{66,62,195}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\LARGE}]
        \draw[color=mycolor] (20.75,10.5) rectangle (16,13.25);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \label{fig:my_labelB}
    \caption{\textcolor{mycolor}{COLORED TEXT}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    % no color redefinition here, so document-wide definition applies
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\LARGE}]
        \draw[color=mycolor] (20.75,10.5) rectangle (16,13.25);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \label{fig:my_labelC}
    \caption{\textcolor{mycolor}{COLORED TEXT}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note:* As pointed out in the comments to your question, you should not use the `tikz` environment, but rather `tikzpicture`. Also, use `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle` (or append global styles as option to the `tikzpicture` environment directly as shown in the above example). Finally, the use of `\resizebox` might not be necessary and should in any case handled with care as it also resizes the font which you might not want.

---

If you *really* need to define colors globally from within a scope, you can do this via `\globalcolorstrue`. But you need to take care then that the colors are named differently, otherwise you would just redefine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% define color for whole document
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{255,0,0}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    % global defintion inside scope
    \globalcolorstrue
    \definecolor{mycolorA}{RGB}{0,255,0}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\LARGE}]
        \draw[color=mycolorA] (20.75,10.5) rectangle (16,13.25);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \label{fig:my_labelA}
    \caption{\textcolor{mycolorA}{COLORED TEXT}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\LARGE}]
        \draw[color=mycolorA] (20.75,10.5) rectangle (16,13.25);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \label{fig:my_labelB}
    \caption{\textcolor{mycolorA}{COLORED TEXT}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\LARGE}]
        \draw[color=mycolor] (20.75,10.5) rectangle (16,13.25);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \label{fig:my_labelC}
    \caption{\textcolor{mycolor}{COLORED TEXT}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a variation, you could define the color with the same name inside the each `figure` environment and then globally define a new color as copy which you can then use outside the `figure` as well. This way, the color name would always be the same inside the `figure` environments, But at least to be able to use all colors in the body text, you somehow need to name the colors differently. You could use the figure number for easy reference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    % local defintion inside scope
    \definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0,255,0}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\LARGE}]
        \draw[color=mycolor] (20.75,10.5) rectangle (16,13.25);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \label{fig:my_labelA}
    \caption{\textcolor{mycolor}{COLORED TEXT}}
    % global copy with different name
    \globalcolorstrue
    \colorlet{mycolor \thefigure}{mycolor}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{255,0,0}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\LARGE}]
        \draw[color=mycolor] (20.75,10.5) rectangle (16,13.25);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \label{fig:my_labelB}
    \caption{\textcolor{mycolor}{COLORED TEXT}}
    \globalcolorstrue
    \colorlet{mycolor \thefigure}{mycolor}
\end{figure}

As shown in \textcolor{mycolor 1}{figure 1} and also in \textcolor{mycolor 2}{figure 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is there any way to refer to the color defined in the scope? I can't place inside the preamble since they are not uniform but dependent on the data (for example colored on a color-scheme). If I want to reference it in my text I would like to no have a polluting global namespace, I also generate individual, self contained files and just replace them if my data changes

Comment: @Leander You can, see the edit to my answer, but you need to take care to name the colors properly.

Comment: that's unfortunate. I generate plots and other visualizations of data and want to refer to the exact color not only in the caption but sometimes in the text. Generating full global names just pollutes the namespace and is also hard to do sensibly. I generate standalone .tex files I place in a separate folder and then load into the figure enviroment. These get overwritten if the data changes.

Comment: @Leander I am really unsure what you want to achieve exactly. You want to use the same color name everywhere but with different definitions in different figures, but then you also want to refer to a specific color of a figure in the body text? How do you then specify which figure (and color) you mean? Maybe you should really extend your code example to something one can make more sense of (this is in general always a good idea to start with).